# similar to their parents/those of their parents, similar to him/his

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1. The children have similar personality traits to their parents.
2. The children have similar personality traits to their parents'.
3. The children have similar personality traits to those of their parents.
4. She has similar interests to him.
5. She has similar interests to his.

Comment: Looking at 1, 2 and 3, which do you think is best and why? The people may be better able to help you.

Comment: All are reasonable. I resist the apostrophe form in 2, but people sometimes disagree with me.